# Calling PHP file in Javascript and hide

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to call php file in this code and disable them?

```js
function validate() {
  var newevent = document.getElementById("chknewevent").checked;

  if(newevent ==  true) { // unchecked
    alert('sample');
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("You are proceeding to Banquet Reservation"); //if checked
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: think you want AJAX but it's unclear.

Comment: @Jasen I am actually creating a user accessibility by module, is there anything you think the easiest way using php?

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, you might find the JQUERY load or getJSON methods helpful.

Comment: @Snake14 Alright, I'll try that one. Thank you :)